# Alternate required inputs in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to have alternate required inputs. My goal to my form is to hide and show the inputs regarding with what position (Faculty Member or Student as options) and store to the database. Different input fields for the Student, as well as different fields too for the Faculty Member. I used this code for my JavaScript hide & show inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fac').hide();
    $('#stud').hide();

    $("#thechoices").change(function(){
    $("#all").children().show();

    $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
    });

    $("#thechoices").change();
    });

    </script>
```

However, when I choose Student (So Student input fields appear now and Faculty Member input fields are hidden), fill up the fields, and click Submit button, I can't proceed to the form action I put because the hidden fields for faculty member are also required to be filled.

And if I eliminate the required attribute on each input, my database could be destroyed (such as multiple inputs, blank inputs). I got almost the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618618/how-to-create-conditional-fields-that-are-required-to-be-filled-out?rq=1) but I still did not understand the given answer. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have used JQuery.

Try this approach.

You can intercept the form submission with this event handler.

Add this to your existing script.

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {

    // check if field is visible
    if ( $("field").is(":visible") ) {
        // validate it
    }
}
```

For more info, Check JQuery Documentation at below links
Form Submit http://api.jquery.com/submit/
Visible selector : http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

HTH

Comment: I called the same JavaScript. I cannot alter the fields in that same function.

Comment: I did not do that. One can down vote if he/she reached 125 rep score.

Comment: I already have the field validation and that is what I did. And I can't really apply your comment if there is no actual sample code or link that I can refer. I've searched enough from Google for some references, found none and here I am asking for an answer of my problem. Or maybe I just need more understanding, idea or knowledge about JavaScript. :(

Comment: I removed my old comments. The approach is similar to the thread you refered in the Original Post but I changed it to suit your question.